# how to mimic android checkbox using button and state drawables

Tags: android, button, checkbox, android-drawable, android-imagebutton

I want to use checkbox in RemoteViews but it does not support Checkbox object, so I think that I can achieve a similar effect using Button with custom state-list drawables. Basically I want an on/off switch which toggles on click and looks like a Checkbox.

I believe I am not the only one having this requirement so maybe someone has already made this checkbox-like button before. Please share with me the xml or point me in a direction. I don't have 100% understanding of drawables but I can find a way through it if I am heading in the right direction.

One shortcut I could take is to use an ImageButton and then alternate the images of checked/unchecked states programmatically, but I think inherent state changes would be faster.

Comment: `... using button and state drawables` Why not using a **TextView** and StateDrawables?

Comment: @BobMalooga Button extends TextView. Why is TextView bolded?

Comment: A TextView is **lighter**. And it can take advantage of **compound drawables**.

Comment: Well, I realized that it will be too much work for aiming a difference of milliseconds in speed, so now I am simply alternating the images. Thanks for the comments though. They will be helpful for me or someone else someday.